# afnetworking with iOS 9 sessions

Tags: ios, afnetworking, ios9, afhttpsessionmanager

I have that big project it's for some websites so I made a subclass from AFHTTPSessionManager as service class, everything was working fine till iOS 9 released, then login doesn't work I checked I get token and everything but I can't use them I mean when I request to see my cars for example server sends me that I am not logged in.
I used those keys for server exception but didnt work.
I am sorry for that lame question.

Comment: Have you added network permissions in info.plist > NSAppTransportSecurity

Comment: yes, but didn't work.

Comment: everything works, but when I want to make request to get something for me as a user, server doesn't see. I think it doesn't see the session or something.

Comment: you seem to have been working with AFHTTPSessionManager,  I am kinda stuck in such issue too, can you have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689244/afhttpsessionmanager-posting-video-swift

Comment: hey racheel I solved my problem. (I wrote it in answer, I don't know if you saw or not.)
can you send me if it worked for you or not :)

Comment: its Raheel :) I solved my problem with using native NSURLSession, but I couldn't get AFHTTPSessionManager woking, but see if you can  answer that question. Question link is in above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this method to my subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *, id, NSError *))completionHandler{

NSMutableURLRequest *req = (NSMutableURLRequest *)request;
[req setValue:headerToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"header"];

return [super dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:completionHandler];}
```

so it's like every time I create data task I will just force it to send the header.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible.

For a quick hack you can do the following,

Add this to the Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```